# Exclude users from belonging to a particular group in G Suite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am trying to write a script in Google apps script that will suspend the account of users whose account has been inactive for than 120 days. But I don't want the script to delete the accounts of users who are in a particular group. The following is the script that I came up with:

```
/**
 * Lists all the users in a domain sorted by first name.
 */
function listAllUsers() {

  var contents = [];
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      customer: 'xyz12345',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        if(user.suspended==false){
          contents.push([user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail, user.creationTime, user.lastLoginTime]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  checkUserLoginTime(contents);
}


/**
 * Check the user Log in Time of the users.
 * @param contents (The array containing the users list)
 */
function checkUserLoginTime(contents) {
  //Logger.log(contents);
  var usersToSuspend = [];
  var timeNow = new Date();
  var checkTime = new Date(); 
  checkTime.setDate(checkTime.getDate()-120);
  checkTime = new Date(checkTime);
  Logger.log('TimeNow:'+ timeNow);
  Logger.log('checktime:'+ checkTime);

  for (var i=0; i<contents.length; i++){
    var fullName = contents[i][0];
    var email = contents[i][1];
    var formattedCreationTime = new Date(contents[i][2]);
    var formattedLastLoginTime = new Date(contents[i][3]);
    Logger.log(fullName);
    Logger.log(email);
    Logger.log(formattedCreationTime);
    Logger.log(formattedLastLoginTime);
    if(formattedCreationTime <= checkTime && formattedLastLoginTime <= checkTime){
      usersToSuspend.push([fullName, email]); 
      Logger.log('The user account is Inactive')
      //suspendUsers(email);
    } else{
      Logger.log('The user account is Active')
    }
  }

}
```

This script will push all the user accounts the array `usersToSuspend`, whose last login time was greater than 120 days. Is there a way to filter out this array or stop pushing the emails to this array which belong to a particular group say for eg: `xyz@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script that finally worked for me without creating a separate function or complex `for loops` is as follows:

```
/**
 * Lists all the users in a domain sorted by first name.
 */
function listAllUsers() {

  var contents = [];
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      customer: 'xyz12345',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        if(user.suspended==false){
          contents.push([user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail, user.creationTime, user.lastLoginTime]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  checkUserLoginTime(contents);
}


/**
 * Check the user Log in Time of the users.
 * @param contents (The array containing the users list)
 */
function checkUserLoginTime(contents) {
  //Logger.log(contents);
  var usersToSuspend = [];
  var timeNow = new Date();
  var checkTime = new Date();
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("xyz@gmail.com");     // gets the group
  var users = group.getUsers();     // gets the users in the group
  checkTime.setDate(checkTime.getDate()-120);
  checkTime = new Date(checkTime);
  Logger.log('TimeNow:'+ timeNow);
  Logger.log('checktime:'+ checkTime);

  for (var i=0; i<contents.length; i++){
    var fullName = contents[i][0];
    var email = contents[i][1];
    var formattedCreationTime = new Date(contents[i][2]);
    var formattedLastLoginTime = new Date(contents[i][3]);
    Logger.log(fullName);
    Logger.log(email);
    Logger.log(formattedCreationTime);
    Logger.log(formattedLastLoginTime);
    if(formattedCreationTime <= checkTime && formattedLastLoginTime <= checkTime){
      if (group.hasUser(email)) {     //checks if the user is part of the group
        Logger.log(email + ' belongs to xyz@gmail.com group');
      } else{
       usersToSuspend.push([fullName, email]); 
       Logger.log('The user account is Inactive')
       //suspendUsers(email);
      }
    } else{
      Logger.log('The user account is Active')
    }
  }

}
```

The [group.hasUser(email)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#hasUser(String)) eliminates the need to run a `for` and `if` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I use to test group membership from a user's email.

```
function testGroupMembership(groupEmail, testUser) {
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail);
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++){
      if ( users[u].getEmail() === testUser){
        return true;
      }
  return false;
}
```

Pass the User's email address and the Group's email address.  If the user is a member, it returns true.  So you would have to "not" or inverse that to suspend the account.